# Display error with breadcrumbs website Odoo 9

Tags: xml, odoo-9, breadcrumbs

I have a problem in the sequence tree view of the article pages in odoo 9
here is the normal display

[image]

if I change to the second or third page it is hidden as the picture:

[image]

it's the template source code:

```
<odoo>

<template id="breadcrumb" name="Breadcrumb snippet">
    <!-- Know if current page is in a menu item -->
    <t t-set="bc_item"
       t-value="request.env['website.menu']
                .search([('url', '=', request.httprequest.path)], limit=1)"/>

    <!-- If so, create the breadcrumbs -->
    <ol t-if="bc_item" class="breadcrumb">
        <!-- Parents -->
        <t t-foreach="bc_item.get_parents(True)" t-as="step">
            <li t-if="step.url or step_first">
                <a t-att-href="step.url or (step_first and '/')">
                    <t t-if="step_first and not step.url">
                        Home
                    </t>
                    <t t-if="not step_first and step.url">
                       <t t-esc="step.name_get()[0][1]"/>
                   </t>
                </a>
            </li>
        </t>

        <!-- Current -->
        <li class="active" t-esc="bc_item.name_get()[0][1]"/>
    </ol>
</template>

</odoo>
```

Comment: You can use `clear_breadcrumbs: true` this argument for your use

Comment: thank you  Keval Mehta  for your reply but where I can add or correct this, it is in website or web ?

Comment: from web you can do this..

Comment: my problem is in website ! 
thanks for all